# Show Enhanced Notes in VisualForce page

Tags: visualforce, related-list, notes, richtext-notes

We had a Visualforce page showing the Notes and Attachments using:

```
<apex:relatedList subject="{!Object__c}" list="CombinedAttachments" />
```

We recently decided to stop using attachments to instead use Enhanced notes and Files. We've already changed all objects layouts to show the new related lists, but the visualforce page still shows the old Notes and Attachments one.

I've managed to show the Files related list (AttachedContentDocuments) but the one for enhanced notes keeps throwing an error with the following message "'AttachedContentNotes' is not a valid child relationship name for entity Process", I've checked the metadata of the object in eclipse and that is the name of the relationship name.

**Works:**

```
<apex:relatedList subject="{!RS_Activity__c}" list="AttachedContentDocuments" />
```

**Doesn't work**

```
<apex:relatedList subject="{!RS_Activity__c}" list="AttachedContentNotes" />
<apex:relatedList subject="{!RS_Activity__c}" list="Notes" />
```

Has anyone managed to show the new enhanced notes in a Visualforce page ?

Thanks

Comment: I'm pretty surprised this doesn't have more votes. Well asked and interesting question.

Comment: not all relationships are supported by VF `relatedList`. You may have found a new one

Comment: @cropredy You're probably right, specially if we consider that enhanced notes where generally added in the Winter 16 release. I hope they will add it in feature releases and it would be really helpful if they had a list with all supported relatedLists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What meta-data apiversion is the visualforce page using? I have a page on version 36.0 with the following mark-up which displays the related list.

```
<apex:relatedList list="AttachedContentNotes" />
```

Also you need to ensure you have enabled enhanced notes in setup > Notes > Note Settings

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/44965)

Comment: @MohithShrivastava - Stuart actually had the markup except it was rendered null; I edited his answer to make it visible

Comment: Stuart is right. I've changed the metadata to version 36 and it works perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for posting this question and answer!

AttachedContentNote is an object that you can find in the Developer Console.  You can attempt to query it using SOQL:

```
SELECT Id, IsDeleted, LinkedEntityId, ContentDocumentId, Title, CreatedById, CreatedDate, LastModifiedById, LastModifiedDate, FileType, ContentSize, FileExtension, TextPreview FROM AttachedContentNote
```

However, you will get the error: "entity type AttachedContentNote does not support query."

So this error led me to try to find out all there is to know about 'AttachedContentNote' by querying the EntityDefinition Object (which DOES support SOQL query):

```
SELECT Id, DurableId, LastModifiedDate, LastModifiedById, QualifiedApiName, NamespacePrefix, DeveloperName, MasterLabel, Label, PluralLabel, DefaultCompactLayoutId, IsCustomizable, IsApexTriggerable, IsWorkflowEnabled, IsProcessEnabled, IsCompactLayoutable, KeyPrefix, IsCustomSetting, IsDeprecatedAndHidden, IsReplicateable, IsRetrieveable, IsSearchLayoutable, IsSearchable, IsTriggerable, IsIdEnabled, IsEverCreatable, IsEverUpdatable, IsEverDeletable, IsFeedEnabled, IsQueryable, IsMruEnabled, DetailUrl, EditUrl, NewUrl, EditDefinitionUrl, HelpSettingPageName, HelpSettingPageUrl, RunningUserEntityAccessId, PublisherId, IsLayoutable, RecordTypesSupported, InternalSharingModel, ExternalSharingModel, HasSubtypes, IsSubtype
FROM EntityDefinition
WHERE DurableId = 'AttachedContentNote'
```

In summary, I think I will query the EntityDefinition object the next time I can't find information on internal objects or I'm getting an error like 'Notes is not a valid related list for this object's page layout.'

Comment: While the answer does start with a "thanks", I think that this is an answer (and a different one than the existing answer). Voting to leave this one be.